# Display Activity Indicator in tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm loading different images in a basic tableview cell and would like to show the activity indicator in the cell while the image is loading. I'm using a separate cell file like sample code. I know where to place the code just not exactly sure about the syntax. I've found a few ways to put code into a view but not specifically in a cell. Anyone have an idea? Thanks.

```
func configureCell(favorite: Article) {
    self.favorite = favorite

    downloadImage(NSURL(string: self.favorite.mainImage)!)

func downloadImage(url: NSURL, type: String) {
    getDataFromUrl(url) { (data, response, error) in
        //show activity indicator
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            guard let data = data where error == nil else { return }
                self.mainImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
}

func getDataFromUrl(url: NSURL, completion: ((data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void)) {

    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) in
        completion(data: data, response: response, error: error)
    }.resume()

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do like below, let me know if that works for you, you can modify the `frame` as per your requirement.

```
func downloadImage(url: NSURL, type: String) {
    let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    activityIndicator.frame = self.mainImage.bounds

    getDataFromUrl(url) { (data, response, error) in
        //show activity indicator
        self.mainImage.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            guard let data = data where error == nil else { return }
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            activityIndicator.removeFromSuperview()
            self.mainImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, that is working! It's just not positioned quite center it's down and to the right but it's showing up. I also had to move self.mainImage.addSubview(activityIndicator) and activityIndicator.startAnimating() above the getDataFromUrl function.

Comment: I can't seem to center it correctly do you know how? I've tried this but it's not quite correct: activityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.mainImage.bounds.width / 2, height: self.mainImage.bounds.height / 2)

Comment: your x,y positions are not correct, you need to center it with respect to super view

Comment: Ahh, thank you. This seems to work pretty good: activityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: self.superview!.frame.width / 2, y: 60, width: 0, height: 0)

Comment: It seems that you are adding indicator after the data has been downloaded. You probably want indication that the image is being downloaded in which case you should add indicator before calling getDataFromURL.